# COURSERA Webpage not loading

Tags: webpage

I am on a highspeed Internet connection. But the coursera website is not loading properly even after clearing the cache or even changing the web browser.The webpage is looking something like the attached image.
I even tried changing the DNS Server, but in vain.

[image]

Comment: This typically only happens with a conflict with a proxy or firewall resulting in content not being properly served to the client.  This problem has nothing to do with DNS, if it was a DNS problem, the content wouldn't be served at all.

Comment: Any idea on how to fix this issue ? Seems like it is only coursera's website that is getting effected.

Comment: Talk to whom ever configured your proxy or firewall

Comment: I am doing this from my home, with no firewall or proxies in between.

Comment: Try using a different browser. While not guaranteed, I have solved similar issues on a handful of misbehaving websites with this method.

Comment: In addition to what has already been mentioned. This can also happen due to script blockers, ad blockers, and tracking blockers. Another thing to look at would be your hosts file. Press **Win + R** to open the run dialog and paste `notepad "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"` to examine the hosts file. As suggested check the website using any other browser to help you identify if it is a browser specific issue.

Comment: It is not browser specific problem, i tried with Mozilla, Edge as well as chrome. But the thing is not yet being resolved.What to examine in the host file ?